# How to solve a problem with Clean URLs in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, urls

I've just migrated a Civi install (version 4.6.25) from Drupal to Wordpress, and all seems to have gone smoothly. I've since updated the Civi install to 5.13.5 (for now the PHP version running on the server precludes further updates). I noted in the docs that with some changes to the code in civicrm.settings.php I can get cleaner URLs in Wordpress, so I implemented the changes as noted, visited the permalink settings page in WP, and cleared my Civi caches for good measure. I can now visit the cleaner URL for my main contribution page, and it loads all the Civi page content, but without any of my site's styling.

My browser console reports that it can't find variable : cj or the variable: CRM.

Any insights into what's going wrong or how to debug this are most welcome. One thing I did consider is that my civicrm.settings.php file obviously dates back to 4.6.25 and maybe it's missing something that would be in there if I'd installed 5.13.5 rather than upgraded to it?

Comment: If it can't load styles or javascript (the cj/CRM part), it sounds like the resource url, under Admin - system settings - Resource URLs. Maybe you still have an old setting there that worked without clean urls but doesn't with clean urls.

Comment: Double checked Resource URL, cleared caches, reloaded contribution page. No change. Looking at the page source in the browser, only the Civi page source is loading, nothing from wordpress. The <head> element is empty.

Comment: @Demerit I tink you have the answer and should post it.  I would also update the settings file as it has changed a bit since 4.6.25

Comment: Further investigation showed that the site in question was running a plugin - Beaver Themer - that was causing the problem. Luckily this plugin has the option of excluding certain pages, i.e. not loading the plugin on those named pages, so we used this and it solves the problem.